# Where to download whole AdventureWorks database?

Tags: sql-server, adventureworks

I've just downloaded and installed the AdventureWorks database from here: http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/releases/view/55926. Bizarrely, the full database is not installed, just only the following tables and views:

- BuildVersion
- Address
- Customer
- CustomerAddress
- Product
- ProductCategory
- ProductDescription
- ProductModel
- ProductModelProductDescription
- SalesOrderDetail
- SalesOrderHeader
- vProductAndDescription
- vProductModelCatalogDescription
- vGetAllCategories
- ErrorLog

Why? Where I get the complete database with all tables/views and so forth?

Comment: I struggled with it some time ago. Basically the scripts don't always run. Do go through the scripts and readme's.

Comment: After reinstalling, it works fine! Note: Donnt confuse "AdventureWorks" with "AdventureWorksLT".

Answer (score 1):

You can download them from Microsoft.com or Github.com

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/samples/adventureworks-install-configure
- https://github.com/Microsoft/sql-server-samples/releases/tag/adventureworks